# Clear site data for a single site in Google Chrome which now redirects

Tags: google-chrome, web

So we switched a website from example.com to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (and implemented a forward to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)). I believe I still have Google Chrome site data which causes problems (Shopware 6 trying to load data via API from example.com - without www) on example.com and this somehow influences [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

I already cleared the site data for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (Chrome dev tools -> Application -> Clear site data)

[image: Screenshot of Dev Tools, Clear Site data]

But how can I do this for example.com which directly forwards me to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) ? I could not find an option in the dev tools to switch the domain I am looking at.

Comment: What problems is it causing is this data causing?  How is shopware configured? If you open your browser's debugging tools, what URLs are actually getting requested and what is their status?  It seems unlikely that cached data is actually the problem here unless you provide some evidence of that being the case.

Comment: Back in 2022 I was pretty convinced that it had to do with some site data, but it's hard to reproduce that case now. It was also more a google-chrome question than a Shopware question. I will remove the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has it`s own DNS-Cache. I had that issue a lot and started to use CURL in the terminal instead when checking whether a redirect is working or not.

But Afaik you can also clear that cache:

1. Open a new tab.
2. Type the url in the search box: chrome://net-internals/#dns
3. Hit the “Clear host cache” button. And you are done as DNS is flushed out.
4. Open another tab and type URL: chrome://net-internals/#sockets
5. Click on the “Flush socket pools” button. Close the Google chrome
   tab.

source: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/google-chrome-clear-or-flush-the-dns-cache/

At least that worked in some cases for me.

Comment: But I don't have DNS problem (I believe) - the redirect is working, but I cannot clear the site data. I am getting calls to https://example.com for API and fonts - not sure where this base URL is stored. My guess would be local storage. In Inkognito and for other users it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that it is a browser problem and not a shopware / server problem? Did you check that the URLs in the html for loading the fonts is the correct URL, or is the old URL still used in the html?

If thats the case you should ensure that you also updated the URL in the sales channel domain settings and also update the `APP_URL` environment variable. After that clear the cache.

Comment: Yes, in Inkognito windows it works